# How can I fix the following error "no match for call to '(std::tr1::shared_ptr<_iobuf*>) (FILE*&)'"

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

given the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>

#include <tr1/memory>  // "tr1" is in order to fix it at Eclipse!
using std::tr1::shared_ptr;  

class CannotOpenFileException: public std::exception {
};

class FileOutput  {
    shared_ptr<FILE*> f;
public:
    FileOutput(const char* filename) {
        FILE* ff = fopen(filename, "w");
        if (ff == nullptr) {
            throw CannotOpenFileException();
        }
        f(ff); //****error
    }
};
```

I get the following error:

> no match for call to '(std::tr1::shared_ptr<_iobuf*>) (FILE*&)'

Why I get this error , and, how can I fix it?

Note: I want to use the functions of C language (at c++) in order to check something, so there is no need to comment on it.

Comment: I guess you want `f.reset(ff);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems:

The first is that the template argument is the *class* that is pointed to. So if you want a pointer to `Foo`, then the template must be `Foo`. In your case you say that `f` is a pointer to a pointer to `FILE`. So the first thing you need to do is to make `f` a pointer to `FILE` by providing the type `FILE` when defining `f`.

The second problem is that the variable `f` is not a function you can call, it's an object. You need to use the objects [`reset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset) function:

```
f.reset(ff);
```

---

Now, regarding the first problem, the solution to it leads to *another* problem. The problem arises because the default deleter for `shared_ptr` does what it sounds like: It tries to `delete` the contained pointer. That's not possible for multiple reasons (like `FILE` being an [opaque data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type), and that the pointer wasn't created with `new`).

This is solved simply by using the `fclose` function as the deleter, and pass it along with to the `reset` call:

```
f.reset(ff, fclose);
```

Comment: @SamerTufail No, for two reasons: First of all the type `FILE*` is the wrong template type, and secondly because then you can't provide a custom deleter.

Comment: sorry I see now, if the type is FILE then you could make_shared without the custom deleter right?

Comment: Why can't you pass `fclose` directly as deleter?

Comment: @el.pescado Because I just didn't think about it, doh! :)